# Best collection to use to store huge data

Tags: java, collections

I need to store huge number of strings in a collection. I dont need a map since I have only the Key. The data size may come upto 4 million or greater. Currently I am using LinkedHashSet. The performance of linkedhashSet is good but it uses hell a lot of memory. I tried LinkedList and it takes too much time.

My requirements are I need to maintain the insertion order. check each item is available in the list/set before throwing a error if its present.

I also tried using comma separated string but it also didnt give much of an improvement.

Could anybody suggest a better solution.

Comment: have you tried TreeSet ?

Answer (score 1):

TreeSet is great to maintain order. 
also be sure you use an appropiate search algorythm to check the Collection for your entry, this can greatly increase your performance!

Comment: I want to maintain the insertion order which treeset doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to implemente a TRIE?It maintains the words sorted in alphabetically orders,and it takes less memory ,because you don't maintain separate object for each string.Instead you store just one char in one Node.
see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8787521
and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: I want to maintain the insertion order which treeset doesnt